# My client side is not working on aws(amazon) Ec2 Instance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services

My project is in MERN(mongo db,express,react and node) stack.My Client side not working on Amazon instance but same client side folder is correctly working on heroku. I made build folder by running command npm build and upload that build folder on Amazon instance.My back end is working but front-end not working.
I am sharing all screen shots[Screen shoot of directory on amazon instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kBPV.png)

i am also sharing my package.json file in client side...By using that file file i created build folder by creating npm run build command. May be some issue there but that build folder correctly working on heroku
**Package.json file in client side**

```
  {
  "name": "now-ui-kit-react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.14",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.53",
    "@pathofdev/react-tag-input": "^1.0.7",
    "async": "^3.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.682.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mdbootstrap": "^4.16.0",
    "mdbreact": "^4.25.6",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.20",
    "move-file": "^2.0.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "nouislider": "14.0.2",
    "npm": "^6.14.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "progressbar": "^1.3.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-apple-login": "^1.0.11",
    "react-audio-player": "^0.13.0",
    "react-audio-waveform": "0.0.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap-switch": "15.5.3",
    "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.1.3",
    "react-howler": "^3.7.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "react-soundplayer": "^1.0.4",
    "react-wavesurfer": "^0.8.6",
    "reactstrap": "8.0.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.88.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.2.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "use-global-hook": "^0.1.12",
    "waveform-data": "^1.4.3",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^2.0.0-beta01"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/now-ui-kit.scss src/assets/css/now-ui-kit.css --source-map true"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

**My index file in build folder (i created build folder by npm run build)**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-icon.png"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/>
      <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ebcffbdb17.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css"/>
      <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.5/iconify.min.js"></script>
      <title>Musicmax</title>
      <link href="/static/css/2.c4e2230b.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="/static/css/main.2398cf45.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script src="semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.2.3/wavesurfer.min.js"></script><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><script>!function(l){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],f=0,i=[];f<n.length;f++)t=n[f],p[t]&&i.push(p[t][0]),p[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(l[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);i.length;)i.shift()();return c.push.apply(c,u||[]),a()}function a(){for(var e,r=0;r<c.length;r++){for(var t=c[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var u=t[o];0!==p[u]&&(n=!1)}n&&(c.splice(r--,1),e=f(f.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},p={1:0},c=[];function f(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return l[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,f),r.l=!0,r.exports}f.m=l,f.c=t,f.d=function(e,r,t){f.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},f.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},f.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=f(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(f.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)f.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},f.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return f.d(r,"a",r),r},f.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},f.p="/";var r=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;a()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/2.9d8867b1.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.8452b760.chunk.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**The console message I got when i upload build folder on amazon instance and then access the public address**

[Screen Shot of console after deploy on amazon instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfpAg.png)

**Note:My that build folder correctly working on heroku but not working on amazon instance but if I upload different project build folder on same instance with same setting then its work.. **

Answer (score 1):

After running npm run build i run that command serve -s build and i can easily access my client side on my local machine.Its mean my build folder at client side working fine. There is some issue at amazon instance
[Screen Shot after run npm run build and run serve -s build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ26Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my Issue actually all things are working fine. There was only issue in one line

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

When I removed that line all things working fine..Now that Query is closed..Thanks all